# Foreach loop with PHP to show each entry in database in a separate text box

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach, textbox

I have a table of questions, and I'd like to use a foreach loop to print out each question separately with a text box and a checkbox next to it. I then need to be able to take any question that is checked and do stuff to them--specifically, take the id of the question and place that in a junction table, as these questions are to be added to a printable file. (It's a test question database). I know how to do foreach loops, but I was wondering if this was possible, and how to iterate the values to make sure each textbox corresponds to a checkbox and the right values are obtainable.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to provide the code you have already tried.

Comment: I hadn't tried anything yet, just wanted to check how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do something like this:
(except that this is not a For Each loop, same concept applies)

```
    <? for ($xlist=0; $xlist<9; $xlist++) { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkSel" id="check_<? =xlist ?>"> <input type="text" value="<? =$yourValue ?>" name="quest" id="quest_<? =xlist ?>">
   <? } ?>
```

That will paint out a checkbox and a question with the same identifier.  That way you can make sure they relate to each other.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I'm able!

Comment: Mine and James' solutions are somewhat the same, but I'm not sure about setting the value as opposed to an ID.  I suppose it's workable either way.

Answer (score 0):

Create an incrementing integer for your loop and put this inside:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='" . $loopIncrementVariable . "' value='" . $valueFromDatabase"'>";
```

You can do the same for the textbox, assigning it the same incrementing value from the loop. They will then both have the same id which can be used to match each other.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I'm able!